# Turn off constraints temporarily (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, constraints, entity-relationship

I'm looking for a way to temporarily turn off all DB's constraints (eg table relationships).

I need to copy (using INSERTs) one DB's tables to another DB.
I know I can achieve that by executing commands in proper order (to not break relationships).

But it would be easier if I could turn off checking constraints temporarily and turn it back on after the operation's finish.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not complete copy I just want to copy selected tables between

Comment: My concern about doing this is that this turns off the constraints for everyone not just you. If you must do this, put the database in single user mode first. Otherwise you can end up data integrity problems.

Comment: Dear people from The Future: You can disable and re-enable all constraints in the database at once; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/161410

Comment: Don't forget to enable the constraints, when done!

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco fair enough; I was going off the `sql-server` and `sql-server-2005` tags. The link I gave is for SQL Server, but you can do the same thing in Oracle - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128623/disable-all-table-constraints-in-oracle) and [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/891801). You can also do it in [PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679854/postgresql-disabling-constraints).

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You can disable FK and CHECK constraints <strike>only in SQL 2005+</strike>. See [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(SQL.90).aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_foo_column
```

Primary keys and unique constraints can not be disabled, but this should be OK if I've understood you correctly.

Comment: But this is not temporary.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: it depends. Yes it is, in that you can re-enable them with DROP/CREATE

Comment: This answer is only the first half of a solution. I was looking for a simple way to turn off constraints temporarily, and I have reached the conclusion that it does not exist, on Oracle.

Comment: It is not true that PKs and unique constraint cannot be disabled. At least in more recent version of SQL Server it works. For example, see: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/primary_keys.php

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco on Oracle?
ALTER TABLE some_table DISABLE CONSTRAINT some_table_fk1;

//do some stuff that would violate the constraints

ALTER TABLE some_table ENABLE CONSTRAINT some_table_fk1;

Answer (score 325):

```
-- Disable the constraints on a table called tableName:
ALTER TABLE tableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

-- Re-enable the constraints on a table called tableName:
ALTER TABLE tableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
---------------------------------------------------------

-- Disable constraints for all tables in the database:
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

-- Re-enable constraints for all tables in the database:
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @kevinc no. As long as you're consitent it doesn't matter.

Comment: Using quoted identifiers is I believe the ANSI standard setting, which means you shouldn't use them for strings.    Has nothing to do with being consistent.   see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: Thanks for the procedure! And BTW it's correct casing is "sp_MSforeachtable" (MS uppercase). Thanks!

Comment: This should have been marked as the correct answer as it answers the question completely. Not only that, but @Donal included a wildcard version which was very helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks for the re-enabling bit. Especially the double `check check` which many folks forget!!

Answer (score 58):

And, if you want to verify that you HAVEN'T broken your relationships and introduced orphans, once you have re-armed your checks, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE foo CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_something
```

then you can run back in and do an update against any checked columns like so:

```
UPDATE myUpdatedTable SET someCol = someCol, fkCol = fkCol, etc = etc
```

And any errors at that point will be due to failure to meet constraints.

Comment: A better way is ALTER TABLE FOO WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_something

Comment: ALTER TABLE foo CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL or ALTER TABLE foo CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_something will enable constraints but without checking data and this means that constraint will be untrusted (is_no_trusted = 1, is_disabled = 0).

Answer (score 18):

You can actually disable all database constraints in a single SQL command and the re-enable them calling another single command. See:

- [Can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-tsql/161410#161410)

I am currently working with SQL Server 2005 but I am almost sure that this approach worked with SQL 2000 as well

Answer (score 3):

**Disabling and Enabling All Foreign Keys**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_Disable_Triggers_v2
    @disable BIT = 1
AS
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)
        ,   @tableName VARCHAR(128)
        ,   @tableSchema VARCHAR(128)

    -- List of all tables
    DECLARE triggerCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  t.TABLE_NAME AS TableName
            ,   t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS TableSchema
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
        ORDER BY t.TABLE_NAME, t.TABLE_SCHEMA

    OPEN    triggerCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM triggerCursor INTO @tableName, @tableSchema
    WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
    BEGIN

        SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tableSchema + '.[' + @tableName + '] '
        IF @disable = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + ' DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ' ENABLE TRIGGER ALL'

        PRINT 'Executing Statement - ' + @sql
        EXECUTE ( @sql )

        FETCH NEXT FROM triggerCursor INTO @tableName, @tableSchema

    END

    CLOSE triggerCursor
    DEALLOCATE triggerCursor
```

> First, the foreignKeyCursor cursor is declared as the SELECT statement
>   that gathers the list of foreign keys and their table names. Next, the
>   cursor is opened and the initial FETCH statement is executed. This
>   FETCH statement will read the first row's data into the local
>   variables @foreignKeyName and @tableName. When looping through a
>   cursor, you can check the @@FETCH_STATUS for a value of 0, which
>   indicates that the fetch was successful. This means the loop will
>   continue to move forward so it can get each successive foreign key
>   from the rowset. @@FETCH_STATUS is available to all cursors on the
>   connection. So if you are looping through multiple cursors, it is
>   important to check the value of @@FETCH_STATUS in the statement
>   immediately following the FETCH statement. @@FETCH_STATUS will reflect
>   the status for the most recent FETCH operation on the connection.
>   Valid values for @@FETCH_STATUS are:
>
> 0 = FETCH was successful
>   -1 = FETCH was unsuccessful
>   -2 = the row that was fetched is missing
>
> Inside the loop, the code builds the ALTER TABLE command differently
>   depending on whether the intention is to disable or enable the foreign
>   key constraint (using the CHECK or NOCHECK keyword). The statement is
>   then printed as a message so its progress can be observed and then the
>   statement is executed. Finally, when all rows have been iterated
>   through, the stored procedure closes and deallocates the cursor.

see [Disabling Constraints and Triggers from MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163442.aspx)