# ERROR: column of relation does not exist PostgreSQL ,Unable to run insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, quoted-identifier

Hi I am trying to insert into a table tester3 it fails when i use the below syntax

```
insert into tester3 (UN0, UN1) values ( 1, 'jishnu1');
```

but below insert

```
insert into tester3 values ( 1, 'jishnu1');
```

works fine.

```
mydb=# CREATE TABLE tester3
mydb-#    (
mydb(#     "UN0" integer,
mydb(#     "UN1" VARCHAR(40)
mydb(#    );
CREATE TABLE
mydb=# insert into tester3 (UN0, UN1) values ( 1, 'jishnu1');
ERROR:  column "un0" of relation "tester3" does not exist
mydb=# \d tester3
           Table "public.tester3"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 UN0    | integer               |
 UN1    | character varying(40) |
```

I think i am missing something very trivial, I tried several other column names some of them works fine and some are not. I am confused.

Does PostgreSQL have restriction in column names for which the first syntax of insert query works?

---

**Edit :**

Checkout Girdon Linoff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31072263/3651739) here , as [Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) pointed out the other column names which were working without quotes were in **lower case**.

> Lower case column is the standard within PostgreSQL and also works without quotes

Comment: You can find details about identifier names here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Very useful for your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651417/escaping-keyword-like-column-names-in-postgres

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you  define the columns with double quotes, then you generally need to use them when you refer to the column:

```
insert into tester3 ("UN0", "UN1")
     values ( 1, 'jishnu1');
```

I would suggest you remove the double quotes from the column names in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

You don't need the double quotes if the name is all lower case.

Comment: Weird, the description of the table does not show the double quotes. But yes, this appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap: That's all lower case, that's the standard within PostgreSQL and also works without quotes.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap you created those columns explicitly as upper case, but then later query for them in a case-insensitive manner, and so they are not found. When you put the names in quotes, the lookup will be case-sensitive.

Comment: @Unglückspilz you should put that out as an answer, because that's the generic issue core :)

Comment: Even if the tables are created without double quotes, these quotes are needed. I created tables in pgAdmin 4 and used .NET Core to insert the data, and it was only possible with the quotation.

Answer (score 11):

> Use double quotes to your column names and single quotes to your
> values

```
insert into tester3 ("UN0", "UN1") values ( 1, 'jishnu1');
```

Answer (score -3):

i have my story with my database for Qgis + POSTGRES DATA
i try update my table with code by Navicate
UPDATE "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310" SET "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310"."Nguon"='Lâm'
and ERRO :
SQL]UPDATE "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310" SET "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310"."Nguon"='Lâm'

### [Err] ERROR:  column "MangLuoi" of relation "A_Lam_D310" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310" SET "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310"."...

Now i try
UPDATE "MangLuoi"."A_Lam_D310" SET "Nguon"='Lâm'

IT show ok :))
by Message:
Time: 0.035s

Affected rows: 29

Thank for share and answer.

Comment: This answer is difficult to read. Please see Stackoverflow's [Style guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).