# postgresql : hstore key as a reserved keyword : any way around?

Tags: postgresql, hstore, reserved-words

Using Postgresql 9.4

I have a table with a hstore field named 'references' :

Trying to do : select * from table where (references -> 'key' = 'value')
results in

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "references"

As it works as expected with another fieldname, I suspect it's because it's a reserved word... but I don't feel like renaming this heavily used field in my application.

So, is there any syntax to work around this problem ?

Comment: (Look at this.)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651417/escaping-keyword-like-column-names-in-postgres]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to David, the solution is :

`select * from table where ( "references"->'key' = 'value' );`

where the meaning of quotes and double-quotes is important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose column names that are keywords in double quotes.

Comment: Yep, I only tried with single quotes around the column name, but it appears  that it does not mean the same thing...

Comment: Single quotes create a literal text string. Double quotes create an identifier (column or table name). See quote_literal and quote_identifer functions.