# Select column name containing forward slash in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and trying the below two scenarios:

1. Select a column name which already has a forward slash(/) in database (Road/Highway)
2. Using `case` on same column along with `index`

```sql
Select Road/Highway, 
case 
 when index(upcase(Road/Highway), 'xturn') > 0 then 2
 else 0
end as preferred_road
from abc_data;
```

But I am getting syntax error near index and for slash it is only taking Road.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2):

Generally `/` means "division", so your column name is non-standard, [much like working with keyword column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7651417/903061), column names with special characters must be quoted with double quotes. Use `"Road/Highway"` when referring to the column.

Comment: Thanks for the correcction!

Comment: Thanks @Gregor , any thoughts on the ```case``` part?

Comment: Use double quotes **everywhere** you refer to the column. Without quotes, it will look for a column name "Road" and a column named "Highway" and try to divide them.