# Postgresql: literal table names

Tags: postgresql, syntax, quoted-identifier

I am making an application that needs to construct Postgresql queries that will execute successfully in scenarios when table names are reserved keywords etc.

In Sql Server syntax this is achieved by wrapping everything in square brackets `[]` i.e. `SELECT * FROM [database].[schema].[table_name]`.

I thought the equivalent in Postgresql was the use of double quotes `""` i.e. `SELECT * FROM "database"."schema"."table_name"`.

However, when I try this in Postgresql I get the error

> Relation X doesn't exist

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM "postgres"."schema_a".Academic_Attainment
```

But this **doesn't**:

```
SELECT * FROM "postgres"."schema_a"."Academic_Attainment"
```

Related to: [Escaping keyword-like column names in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651417/escaping-keyword-like-column-names-in-postgres)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the actual name of the table, how was it created? Maybe it's `"academic_attainment"` - notice that in quotes, case matters.

Comment: I'm guessing the table name is not actually Academic_Attainment but academic_attainment. If the table was created without double quoting the table name then it would get folded to all lower case. See here [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) unquoted identifiers are folded to lowercase.

A quoted identifier is also case sensitive, so `"Foo"` is a different name than `"foo"`.

So the name `Academic_Attainment` is the same as `academic_attainment`. If you really insist on using those dreaded double quotes, then you need to use a lower case identifier:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "schema_a"."academic_attainment"
```

In general it's [strongly recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)  to **not** use quoted identifiers at all. As a rule of thumb: never use double quotes and you are fine.

---

If you are constructing dynamic SQL, use the `format()` function to do that together with the `%I` placeholder. It will take care of quoting if necessary (and only then), e.g.

`format('select * from %I.%I', 'public', 'some_table')` yields `select * from public.some_table` but `format('select * from %I.%I', 'public', 'group')` yields `select * from public."group"`

---

Unrelated to your question: Postgres doesn't support cross-database queries, so you should not get into the habit including the database name into your fully qualified names. The syntax you are using only works because you are connected to the database `postgres`. So I would recommend to stop using the database name in any table reference.