# Syntax error at or near "order" (Scala with Quill, Doobie and PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, scala, orm, doobie

I am using Quill with Doobie and PostgreSQL (`org.tpolecat.doobie-quill` artifact with version 0.13.1).

This code

```scala
case class SomeRecord(id: Int, order: Int, name: String)

val record = SomeRecord(0, 0, "test")

run(
  quote(
    querySchema[SomeRecord]("some_table")
  ).insert(lift(record))
)
```

Will end up in error message in runtime:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"
> Position: 46
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
> at doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter$PreparedStatementInterpreter.$anonfun$executeUpdate$5(kleisliinterpreter.scala:955)
> at doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter$PreparedStatementInterpreter.$anonfun$executeUpdate$5$adapted(kleisliinterpreter.scala:955)
> at doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter.$anonfun$primitive$2(kleisliinterpreter.scala:109)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Quill does not escape keyword-like column names, so "order" (and other keywords) columns in it's query will always fail. See [Escaping keyword-like column names in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651417/escaping-keyword-like-column-names-in-postgres) . The workaround is to rename the column in table (and corresponding case classes).