# Update field named 'from' in table postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to update field named 'from' in postgres. But i can not to do it.

Select working such:

```
SELECT table_name.from FROM table_name WHERE id=1
```

But I can not do it with UPDATE:

```
production=# UPDATE table_name SET from='text' WHERE id=3482;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
production=# update table_name set table_name.from='text' where id=3482;
ERROR:  column "table_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist
LINE 1: update table_name set table_name.from='
```

Can you suggest a way to update a field 'from' in the table?

Comment: Have you tried using quotes around the `from` (like `SELECT table_name."from" FROM table_name WHERE id=1`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651417/escaping-keyword-like-column-names-in-postgres for more details

Comment: Its not working
ERROR:  column "table_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist
or
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'from'"
LINE 1: update table_name set table_name.'from'=

Comment: Mandatory read: [Identifiers and Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the Postgres manual

Comment: O! Its working!
production=# update "table_name" set "from"='text' where id=3482;
UPDATE 1
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes as such:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET "from"='text' WHERE id=3482;
```

Look at [4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

> Change "from" to Your "Field Name"
> UPDATE table_name SET "from" = value1 where id=1

Comment: Please share more details. I would assume that `from` **is** the name of the column

Comment: The column **is** named `from` - that's the problem