# How do I escape database table and column names for PostgreSQL in VBA?

Tags: vba, string, postgresql, ms-access, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate an Access database to a PostgreSQL DB, and lots of table names or column names have space or number, for instance, table name: "test history" and "123 people", and column name: "test history". I'm keeping getting SQL syntax errors because of these spaces and numbers.

```
 'create tables in PostgreSQL database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        Dim strCreateTable As String
        strCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " &  tdf.Name  & " ("
        For Each fld In tdf.fields
            strCreateTable = strCreateTable &  fld.Name  & " " & GetPostgreSQLDataType(fld.Type) & ","
        Next fld
        strCreateTable = Left(strCreateTable, Len(strCreateTable) - 1) & ")"
        'MsgBox strCreateTable
        cnn.Execute strCreateTable
    End If
Next tdf
```

Just wondering if there is a way to transfer the output of table name and column name to a string.

Comment: [Postgres uses double-quotes `"` to escape object identifiers like table-names and column-names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651417/escaping-keyword-like-column-names-in-postgres).

Comment: I've tried to put " " in the code, but the output becomes "CREATE TABLE tdf.Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to migrate an Access database to a PostgreSQL DB

**Good** <sub>(I'm of the opinion MS Access needs to die a dignified death instead of circling the drain for another 20 years...)</sub>

> and lots of table names or column names have space or number, for instance, table name: "`test history`" and "`123 people`", and column name: "`test history`". I'm keeping getting SQL syntax errors because of these spaces and numbers.

[PostgreSQL follows ANSI/ISO SQL so it uses double-quotes `"` to delimit object-identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651432/159145), whereas Access (aka *JET Red* and *ACE*) uses square-brackets `[]`.

So it's just a matter of ensuring object-identifiers in your SQL strings are delimited with `"` *within* the VBA Strings - which isn't *that bad* as VBA uses `""` within a string as an escape-sequence for double-quotes.

So this should work for you (I've also added some additional whitespace and `NULL/`NOT NULL` handling too):

```vb
Sub GenerateAndExecuteCreateTableStatements()

    ' Create tables in PostgreSQL database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        
            Dim createStmt As String
            createStmt = GetCreateTableSql(tdf)

            ' Consider using Debug.Print instead of MsgBox to dump variables:
            Debug.Print createStmt
            cnn.Execute createStmt

        End If
    Next tdf

End Sub

Function GetCreateTableSql(tbl As DAO.TableDef)

    Dim createStmt As String
    createStmt = "CREATE TABLE """ &  tbl.Name  & """ ("
    
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each fld In tbl.Fields

        Dim column As String
        column = vbTab & """" & fld.Name & """" & " " & GetPostgreSQLDataType(fld.Type) & Iif(fld.Required, " NOT NULL", " NULL")

        If i > 0 Then
            column = "," & vbCrLf & column
        End If
        i = i + 1

        createStmt = createStmt & column
     Next
     
    ' Add closing parenthesis:
    createStmt = createStmt & vbCrLf & ")"

    ' Return it:
    GetCreateTableSql = createStmt

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but it's giving me an error message: runtime error 424 "object required".

Comment: @Shensuper On which line?

Comment: createStmt = "CREATE TABLE """ & tdf.Name & """ ("

Comment: @Shensuper I've corrected my answer - it's because I renamed `tdf` to `tbl` for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow the tailing comma is still there,  here is one of the output：
CREATE TABLE "Treatment" (  
"TreatmentName" VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    "WitholdingPeriod" SMALLINT NULL,
    "ExportSlaughterInterval" SMALLINT NULL,
    "BatchNo" VARCHAR(255) NULL,
)

Comment: @Shensuper Try again now - I've changed the code that added commas and newlines between columns.