# SQL query not returning any results when it should

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql query in my php script that has this line in it:

```
WHERE beerStyle = \"$styleName\" AND rating > 0
```

The style name that is being looked up is:

```
Fresh "Wet" Hop Ale
```

Which is being stored exactly has written above in my database. My problem is I think somehow the quotes are getting mixed up when it looks in the DB, so it thinks there are now styles with that name.

Comment: [Double quotes are the wrong quotes to use here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql).

Comment: This does not answer your question, but just be careful: this code has a sql injection flaw.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string($styleName)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$styleName=mysqli_real_escape_string($styleName);
```

and your query goes like.

```
WHERE beerStyle = $styleName AND rating > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may try

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM beers WHERE beerStyle = '" .$styleName. "'";
```