# php script not connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php "verifyconect.php" script which has my connection to the server. When I fill out my form page it is meant to write the data to the MySQL database but it does not do this. I have also changed the hostname to "localhost" although this is being hosted on the web. I inputted the server hostname which works with my FTP software but no change occurs. Please what am I getting wrong.

verifyconect.php

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect ("hostname", "###", "###");
      mysql_select_db ("dbtable", $link);
?>
```

VerifyLogin.php

```
<?php
include("verifyconect.php");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

$insert = 'INSERT INTO verifytable (username, email, password, confirm_password) VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$confirm_password.'")';

mysql_query($insert);
?>
```

Comment: which kind of error r u facing ?

Comment: add "print mysql_error();" after "mysql_query($insert);" and post what you get.

Comment: try $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: word of advice .. never do something like this ->"'.$username.'"<- in the wild(=live) .. always ...always ...always! use "'.mysql_real_escape_string($username).'"  or you will be hacked in no time ...

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a software which allows you to manage databases, but the table is created within MySQL server. **What error do you get?** ([enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) + `echo mysql_error();`)

Comment: Keep in mind, all mysql_ functions have been deprecated, mysql_connect as an example: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php.  You ought to be using mysqli_* functions moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are switching up the single and double quotes.

Suppose

```
username = john
email = john@example.com
password = hell0w0rld
confirm = hell0w0rld
```

then the query will be this:

```
INSERT INTO verifytable (username, email, password, confirm_password) VALUES ("john", "john@example.com", "hell0world", "hell0w0rld")
```

Using double quotes in SQL queries give a syntax error. To use literal values in SQL queries, you must use single quotes.

So if you rewrite the line with your `$insert` variable to the following:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO verifytable (`username`, `email`, `password`, `confirm_password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$confirm_password."')";
```

you will be good.

*Also note that I surrounded the SQL table column names with backticks, so if you use a keyword (like `password`) as column name, it won't give syntax errors.*

#### Update

It seems that in some cases using double quotes for (literal) values to insert into a SQL table, sometimes will work too. However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql#1992331), you better stick to single quotes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please `Using double quotes in SQL queries give a syntax error` I seem to be missing something here

Comment: @asprin When you take a look at the query stored in the PHP variable `$insert`, then you see that the OP uses single quotes around a PHP string literal, and double quotes in his SQL query. So the query `INSERT INTO test (email) VALUES ("john@example.com")` (with the double quotes) is not valid, it gives an error: `Unknown column 'john@example.com' in 'field list'`. Replace the double quotes by single quotes like this: `INSERT INTO test (email) VALUES ('john@example.com')` and the error is gone.