# Postgresql confuses property as table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use a property that has a .(d0t) in the the propery name, but it seems like postgresql is confused and thinks that i'm trying to access a table property.

Here is the sql query i'm trying to run

```
select count(metadata.username), metadata.username from appointment join appointment_wrapper a on a.id=appointment_wrapper_id where property='state' and string_value='Kano' and timestamp > '2014-08-01' and timestamp < '2014-11-01' group by metadata.username;
```

When i run that query it says

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "metadata"
```

When i add quotes it says

```
ERROR:  non-integer constant in GROUP BY
```

Any help on how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Just to make sure, you quoted the column name in both select and group by clause?

Comment: I tried to using back quotes by it yields the same error as without quotes 

    select count(`metadata.username`), `metadata.username` from appointment join appointment_wrapper a on a.id=appointment_wrapper_id where property='state' and string_value='Kano' and timestamp > '2014-08-01' and timestamp < '2014-11-01' group by `metadata.username`;

Comment: I think back quotes are just for MySQL and double quotes work for Postgres. See @mabi 's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a ["quoted identifier"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) that you obtain by enclosing your column name in *double*quotes to prevent it from being interpreted as a keyword:

```
SELECT count("metadata.username") from app group by "metadata.username";
```

Just a [reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql) that you really, really want to avoid the confusion that having reserved characters in your column or table names bring.