# Incorrect syntax near' error while executing dynamic sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I use dynamic sql for read products in my project.
I want with the number for statment create sql statment
my code is :

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Asbabbazi_A
    @name_product nvarchar(50),
    @first_price int,
    @final_price int,
    @max_registered_price int, 
    @collection_1 nvarchar(30),
    @id_state tinyint,
    @first smallint,
    @final smallint AS
begin
DECLARE @SQLstring nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @PARAMS nvarchar(1000); 
set @SQLstring = 'SELECT IDproduct,name_product,first_price,final_price,max_registered_price,date_record_shamsi,final_date_view_shamsi,
                   count_views,image_1,collection_1 from Table_asbabbazi where active=0'
if(@name_product != "no name")
@SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (name_product  LIKE '%'+(@name_product)+'%')'
 if (@finalPrice != 0)
 @SQLstring = @SQLstring +  'AND ( first_price between  @first_price AND @final_price )'
  if (subCollection != "انتخاب کنید")
 @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (collection_1=@collection_1  )'
 if (state != 0)
 @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (id_state=@id_state  )'
 set @PARAMS ='   @name_product nvarchar(50),
    @first_price int,
    @final_price int,
    @max_registered_price int, 
    @collection_1 nvarchar(30),
    @id_state tinyint,
    @first smallint,
    @final smallint '
     Execute sp_Executesql @SQLstring,
      @name_product ,
    @first_price ,
    @final_price ,
    @max_registered_price , 
    @collection_1 ,
    @id_state ,
    @first ,
    @final 
    end

    RETURN
```

Error message content is:

Incorrect syntax near '@SQLstring'.

Must declare the scalar variable "@finalPrice".

Incorrect syntax near '@SQLstring'.

Incorrect syntax near '@SQLstring'.

It dont work and show error message
please help

Comment: Your posting looks like a mess -clean up. And if you can't get us any error message minimize your query, i.e. remove a small part of your query and try again etc, until you've found the problem.

Comment: if (subCollection != "انتخاب کنید") and if(@name_product != "no name"), why does this have double quote instead of single? There are a lot of other things that needs to be fixed as well. Have you checked this at all? I also cannot see you using SET right before the @SQLString. You should take a look at MSSQL language syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Among other possible errors, You need to add spaces either to the beginning or end (or both) of all strings to make sure they don't collide.

As it stands this block:

```
set @SQLstring = 'SELECT IDproduct,name_product,first_price,final_price,max_registered_price,date_record_shamsi,final_date_view_shamsi,
                   count_views,image_1,collection_1 from Table_asbabbazi where active=0'
if(@name_product != "no name")
@SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (name_product  LIKE '%'+(@name_product)+'%')'
```

will collide the `active=0` at the end of the first string and `AND` at the beginning of the next string:

```
... active=0AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should definitely check SQL syntax for MSSQL. You have a couple of errors. First of all, why are you using double quotes for the following?

```
if (subCollection != "انتخاب کنید") 

if(@name_product != "no name")
```

Second of all, why don't you have SET right before @SQLString?

Try the following;

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Asbabbazi_A
    @name_product nvarchar(50),
    @first_price int,
    @final_price int,
    @max_registered_price int, 
    @collection_1 nvarchar(30),
    @id_state tinyint,
    @first smallint,
    @final smallint AS
begin
DECLARE @SQLstring nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @PARAMS nvarchar(1000); 
set @SQLstring = 'SELECT IDproduct,name_product,first_price,final_price,max_registered_price,date_record_shamsi,final_date_view_shamsi,
                   count_views,image_1,collection_1 from Table_asbabbazi where active=0'
if(@name_product != 'no name')
 SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (name_product  LIKE '%'+(@name_product)+'%')'
 if (@final_price != 0)
 SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring +  'AND ( first_price between  @first_price AND @final_price )'
 if (subCollection != 'انتخاب کنید')
 SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (collection_1=@collection_1  )'
 if ([state] != 0)
 SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (id_state=@id_state  )'
 set @PARAMS ='   @name_product nvarchar(50),
    @first_price int,
    @final_price int,
    @max_registered_price int, 
    @collection_1 nvarchar(30),
    @id_state tinyint,
    @first smallint,
    @final smallint '
     Execute sp_Executesql @SQLstring,
      @name_product ,
    @first_price ,
    @final_price ,
    @max_registered_price , 
    @collection_1 ,
    @id_state ,
    @first ,
    @final 
    end

    RETURN
```

You should definitely read about SQL.

Also, please see the single vs double quote and their usages;

[What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Comment: Explain that double quotes are for identifiers (table names, column names etc), and single quotes are for character strings.

Comment: @jarlh I would assume this would be known. Writing a stored procedure in SQL is a level 300 class. But will do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see just from the syntax highlighting that there is a problem.  For instance, in this line:

```
@SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (name_product  LIKE '%'+(@name_product)+'%')'
```

The `'%'` character is not part of any string.  You need additional single quotes:

```
@SQLstring = @SQLstring + 'AND (name_product  LIKE ''%''' + @name_product + '''%'')'
```

This may be the only problem.  Or not.  If not, I would suggest that you start as simply as possible `select <col> from <table>` and incrementally add to the code to spot problems one by one.  The quoting on dynamic SQL can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code, and it works now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  dbo.Asbabbazi_A
    (@name_product nvarchar(50),
    @first_price int,
    @final_price int,
    @collection_1 nvarchar(30),
    @id_state tinyint)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLstring nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @PARAMS nvarchar(1000)  
set @SQLstring = 'SELECT IDproduct,name_product,first_price,final_price,max_registered_price,
                  date_record_shamsi,final_date_view_shamsi,
                   count_views,image_1,collection_1 from Table_asbabbazi where active=0 '
if(@name_product != 'no name')
set @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' AND (name_product  LIKE %@name_product%)'
if (@final_price != 0)
set @SQLstring = @SQLstring +  ' AND ( first_price between  @first_price AND @final_price )'
if (@collection_1 != 'انتخاب کنید')
set @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' AND (collection_1=@collection_1  )'
if (@id_state != 0)
set @SQLstring = @SQLstring + ' AND (id_state=@id_state  )'

execute @SQLstring
END
```