# SQL Server double quotes issue

Tags: sql-server, datediff, double-quotes

Let's take an example.

The `DATEDIFF` function has this signature:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

`datepart` must by an SQL keyword. Lets say, for minute, we mai use one of those keywords: `minute`, `mi`, `m`.

If I am going to execute this statement

```
select datediff(mi,'2012-April-09','2013-April-08')
```

it will have the exact same effect as this one:

```
select datediff("mi",'2012-April-09','2013-April-08')
```

What is happening when those double quotes are met?

What is SQL Server going to do with what in inside double quotes?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Comment: Specifying the first argument in double quotes is not documented. It happens to work (apparently it's parsed as an identifier, so `[mi]` will work as well), but don't use it. There's no guarantee this will continue to work in later versions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's unlikely to change, since it's part of the SQL standards. The `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` setting in SQL Server [defaults to on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)

Comment: @TZHX: Quoted identifiers, yes. But `DATEDIFF` is not ANSI SQL (`EXTRACT` is), so that the first argument is an identifier isn't specified anywhere (and is surprising to me).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server interprets the option enclosed as a string in the same way it would without it, or as if it were enclosed in other characters for that use -- like `[` and `]` -- and matches it against the [list of valid `datediff` options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx). If it doesn't match, then it returns an error (Msg 155) at the parsing stage and the query will not run (which may result in other parts of the query not running, if it is part of a larger script) and if it does match, then it continues as normal.

Comment: If this is the case then why does `select datediff('mi','2012-April-09','2013-April-08')` not work? Double quotes aren't string delimiters in TSQL.

Comment: Because a string is not a valid input to the function. The transition happens in the parsing, where the object in the double quotes is is evaluated as if it didn't have them. In this situation, `"mi"` and `[mi]` are equivalent.