# Python pymySQL sending a string with quotes

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert a string to a mySQL database like this:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE connections SET cmd = "' + command + '", client_new = 1 where ip = "' + ip + '"')
```

When I set `command` to be `echo "hello"`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/master.py", line 111, in <module>
    main ()
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/master.py", line 80, in main
    print(""); command(); print("")
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/master.py", line 29, in command
    cur.execute('UPDATE connections SET cmd = "' + command + '", client_new = 1 where ip = "' + ip + '"')
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 146, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 296, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 781, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 942, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1138, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 906, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 367, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 120, in raise_mysql_exception
    _check_mysql_exception(errinfo)
  File "M:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 112, in _check_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errorvalue)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'hello"", client_new = 1 where ip = "123.456.789.012"\' at line 1')
```

I understand that there is a problem with how I'm passing the data to the database, but how do I do it properly?

Comment: It appears you are having problems with quotation marks. I'd try to make a variable nawet 'query', then build query string in it and lastly print it to see if it's proper mySQL statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use placeholders, in that case mysql driver escapes your query:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE connections SET cmd=%s, client_new=1 where ip=%s', (command, ip))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are surrounding your SQL string literals with double quotes.  SQL requires string literals to have single quotes.

In SQL, double quotes normally signify identifier names, e.g. if you had a column name with a space in it, you would use double quotes then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: MySQL happily accepts double quotes for both string and other (i.e. integer) values. e.g. insert into rr set idA=1,idB="1",name= Cigar"; works just fine

Comment: AWS RDS still does not accept double quotes unfortunately.