# how to insert \ backslash before quotes in string python

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping

I want to insert a \ before each quotes in my string to insert it to my SQL database using pymysql. If I don't escape quotes I can not insert strings in my database.

For exemple:

> str = "ok I'm ready"

must be :

> str = "ok I\'m ready"
>
> but print str must be : "ok I'm ready"

To perform it I have done:

```
str = str.replace("'", "\'")
```

But it's not working and I still can not insert my string in my database. I have the error message :

> (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's Semantic Search software can power everything from intuitive
>   chatbots to searc' at line 1"): ProgrammingError Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "/var/task/setter_organizations.py", line 38,
>   in handler structured_data.insert() File
>   "/var/task/setter_organizations.py", line 107, in insert
>   self.rds.insertItem(self.type, self.data) File "/var/task/RDS/rds.py",
>   line 92, in insertItem return self.insert(req) File
>   "/var/task/RDS/rds.py", line 35, in insert affected_rows =
>   self.cursor.execute(request) File "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 166, in execute result = self._query(query) File
>   "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query conn.query(q)
>   File "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query
>   self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
>   File "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in
>   _read_query_result result.read() File "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read
>   first_packet = self.connection._read_packet() File
>   "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet
>   packet.check_error() File "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/connections.py", line
>   393, in check_error err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data) File
>   "/var/task/RDS/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
>   raise errorclass(errno, errval) ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Semantic
>   Search software can power everything from intuitive chatbots to searc'
>   at line 1")

I also would print my string and don't see the \

Does anyone know how can I do ?

Comment: "it's not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* isn't working? *How* isn't it working? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: this is because \ is an escape character. Add another one and you're fine

Comment: So basically you want to escape such characters when your inserting it into the SQL database using an SQL query correct?

Comment: yes exactly @code_byter

Comment: @JakyChane Please see my edit.

Comment: @JakyChane I have edited again, for MySQL specific answer. Please post your MySQL connection code as well, if possible.

Comment: @JakyChane it sounds like you are trying to find a way to escape the `'` characters in a string without using a `\ ` - this is oxymoronic. An escaped mysql string contains `\ `, there's no way around that afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, but is not what the OP wanted:

```
str = "ok I'm ready"
str = str.replace("'", "\\'")
print(str)
```

EDIT:

Please take a look at this question: [A good way to escape quotes in a database query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897020/a-good-way-to-escape-quotes-in-a-database-query-string)

And this other one: [Escape string Python for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617052/escape-string-python-for-mysql)
They used:

```
conn.escape_string()
```

EDIT 2:
Please see this:
[Python pymySQL sending a string with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933025/python-pymysql-sending-a-string-with-quotes)

and note how they have used placeholders:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE connections SET cmd=%s, client_new=1 where ip=%s', (command, ip))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @code_byter, I'm using pymysql and I don't know how to use escape_string with it

Comment: @JakyChane check my edit

Answer (score 6):

You should add a second `\`:

```
your_str= your_str.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but it does : ok I\'m ready when printing if I put a second \

Comment: @JakyChane isn't that what you are expecting?

Comment: this is you want right?

Comment: It's not correct. Don't understand why this answer got several upvotes.

Comment: @Nurzhan Please, specify why

Comment: @CarlesMitjans Read the question carefully.

Comment: @Nurzhan you are not being specific

Comment: I have edited my question, I want to escape the quotes but I don't want to see the \ when I print the string

Comment: As an aide try in the interpreter `>>> repr(s.replace("'", "\'"))` to think about string representation; also please don't shadow the in-built `str`, use a different name

Comment: @JakyChane If you escape single quotes, the string will contain `'\'`. Also, your expected string is `"ok I\'m ready"`, how does that not contain `'\'`?

Comment: @JakyChane are you asking how to end up with the string `'ok I'm ready'` in your mysql database? I'm pretty sure that that is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

if you try this will displayed `"ok I\\'m ready"` in terminal actually its `"ok I\'m ready"` you need to print it .

The result '\&' is only displayed - actually the string is \&:

```
str = "ok I'm ready"
str = str.replace("'", "\\'")
```

or

```
str = "ok I'm ready".replace("'","\\'")
```

do,

```
print str  # python 2

print(str) # python 3
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem simply use `r` before text like following:

```
str = r"ok I\'m ready"
```

No need to replace.

Comment: `r` means the string will be treated as raw string.

Comment: then, how do you add 'r' to a string variable which contains " ' " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use double backlash:

```
str = "ok I\\'m ready"
```

Edit: 
Now that you clarify, a way to solve it is `json.dumps("I'm")`

Comment: But I don't to see \ when I print the string...

Comment: @JakyChane That's what you mention in the description.