# PymySQL insert and update separing request to param values

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, pymysql

I'm separing my request to the values for more security, using pymysql for python 2.7.

I have dynamic parameters so I'm using .join() to build my request.

This is how I do:

```
def updateItem(self, table, body, where):
    print 'updateItem'
    if body is not None:
        if body["data"]:
            key_list = []
            for key, data in zip(body['keys'], body['data']):
                placeholder = '{} = '.format(key) + '%s'
                key_list.extend([placeholder])
                val_list = ", ".join(key_list)
            req = """UPDATE """ +table+ """ SET {values} WHERE {where_key}={where_value};""".format(table=table, values=val_list, where_key=where[0], where_value=where[1])
            print req
            params = '"' + '", "'.join(body['data']) + '"'
            print params
            return self.update(req, (params))
```

And:

```
def update(self, request, params):
    print request
    try:
        affected_rows = self.cursor.execute(request, params)
        self.connexion.commit()
        logger.info("Affected rows: " + str(affected_rows))
        return affected_rows
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

The first print give me:

> UPDATE organizations SET uuid = %s, permaname = %s, name = %s,
>   short_description = %s, description = %s, website = %s, is_startup =
>   %s, is_corporate = %s, logo = %s, headcount_min = %s, headcount_max =
>   %s, is_closed = %s, number_of_investments = %s WHERE
>   uuid=3325e470-542a-44cd-b094-3fcfd55bb32c;

And the second is :

> "c7ba44f9-xxx-4a7b-89b0-xxxxx", "xxx-2",
>   "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx is your higher xxxxxx advisor, guiding
>   you to the xxxright course and xxxxx and the No. 1 xxxxx site
>   in xxxxx.", "xxxxx is your higher xxxx advisor, guiding
>   you to the xxxx xxxx and xxx and the Noxxxxxxx xxx site
>   in xxxxx.", "http://xxxxxxxxx.my/", "0", "1",
>   "http://xxx.xxxxx.xx/t_api_images/xxxxx/rgyzkulb0mslq9qbvien.jpg",
>   "51", "100", "0", "0"

I have this error message :

> not enough arguments for format string: TypeError Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "/var/task/setter_organizations.py", line 38,
>   in handler structured_data.insert() File
>   "/var/task/setter_organizations.py", line 109, in insert
>   self.update(["uuid", uuid]) File "/var/task/setter_organizations.py",
>   line 112, in update self.rds.updateItem(self.type, self.data, where)
>   File "/var/task/RDS/rds.py", line 87, in updateItem return
>   self.update(req, (params)) File "/var/task/RDS/rds.py", line 51, in
>   update raise e TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

There is 13 keys and 13 values.
I can not figure out what is wrong in my code, does anyone can help me ?

I also don't know how manage if I have quotes like " or ' in of of my fields, so any answer would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out a similar question's answer that I have given here: [how to insert \ backslah before quotes in string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820628/how-to-insert-backslah-before-quotes-in-string-python/44820661#44820661)

For 13 arguments, you would modify it to something like this:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE table_name SET arg1=%s, num=1 where arg2=%s and arg3=%s and ...upto 13 args',(val1, val2,val3,...upto 13 values))
```

EDIT: (13 value update for 1 where clause)

```
cur.execute('UPDATE table_name SET arg1=%s, arg2=%s, arg3=%s, ...upto 13 args where where_column=val',(val1, val2,val3,...upto 13 values))
```

Comment: ok but that only answer to a part of my question and I m not sur it exist escape_string for pymysql @code_byter

Comment: See EDIT 2 in the link. The other part of your question is about the number of arguments you have supplied. I am still trying to figure that out. Please wait.
EDIT:
I have a strong feeling the way you are passing the params is the reason its not able to get those 13 arguments.Try supplying all 13 arguments individually to see if it works.

Comment: But how can I do insert if I follow your way ?

Comment: `cur.execute('UPDATE table_name SET arg1=%s, num=1 where arg2=%s and arg3=%s and ...upto 13 args',(val1, val2,val3,...upto 13 values))`

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to make it clearer ?

Comment: @JunkyKiller edited. Do tell me if I have not understood your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help @code_byter, but in my case I want to update 13 value for only one where value

Comment: that's not what I ve did ? I did : cur.execute("UPDATE organizations SET uuid = %s, permaname = %s, name = %s, short_description = %s, description = %s, website = %s, is_startup = %s, is_corporate = %s, logo = %s, headcount_min = %s, headcount_max = %s, is_closed = %s, number_of_investments = %s WHERE uuid=3325e470-542a-44cd-b094-3fcfd55bb32c;", (all values))

Comment: Yes, but you've used params to store them. I'm asking you to try them individually. So basically, you will have 13 variables in place of `params`

Comment: Understood! But all my values are in a dict, so how can I pass them individually ?

Comment: if I do : cur.execute('UPDATE table_name SET arg1=%s, arg2=%s, arg3=%s, ...upto 13 args where where_column=val',(dict['value'])) it like giving this in parameter... ['09e1b295-2d9e-4a52-85fe-7c1d5215', u'afterschool-2', u'Afterschool', u'Afterschool is your higher education advisor, nd institution ahe Nysia.', u'Afterschool is your higher edisor, guiding you to the right course and institution and the No. 1 education site in.', u'http://afterschool.my/', u'0', u'1', u'http://public.crunchbase.com/t_api_images/v1489043271/rgyzkulb0mslq9qbvien.jpg', u'51', u'100', '0', u'0']

Comment: Do you know how to do the insert following this method @code_byter ?

Comment: I'm sorry, confused why you ticked my answer, if it was not resolved? Can you explain your above question again?