# Doctrine 2 DQL CONCAT fields and constant strings

Tags: mysql, string, doctrine-orm, concatenation

I have the fields `firstname` and `lastname` in my MySQL table. For convenience, I want to add a computed column to my Doctrine 2 entity called `full_name`. In plain old MySQL I would do something like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) AS full_name FROM customers;
```

However, concatenating fields and constant strings (" " in this case) seems not to work with Doctrine's implementation of CONCAT. When using the following code

```
$repository
    ->createQueryBuilder('customer')
    ->select('CONCAT(customer.firstname, " ", customer.lastname) AS full_name')
    // ...
```

I get the error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 91: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '"'
```

How can I achieve the same behavior as in MySQL?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Apparently, strings in DQL can only be encapsulated by single quotes, not double quotes. A brief search in the documentation did not turn up a direct mention of this behavior, but I noticed that all examples which included constant strings used single quotes.

Changing

```
->select('CONCAT(customer.firstname, " ", customer.lastname) AS full_name')
```

to

```
->select('CONCAT(customer.firstname, \' \', customer.lastname) AS full_name')
```

or

```
->select("CONCAT(customer.firstname, ' ', customer.lastname) AS full_name")
```

solved the issue

Comment: Could you share full example of it? An error says Unknow column full_name. @Subsurf

Comment: Unfortunately, since I have asked this question, the code containing my initial problem has been removed from our codebase, so I can't give an example right now. There must be some other error in your query.

Comment: For the record, this is not surprising at all because the same is also true for SQL in general. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: That's good to know, I am mostly working with MySQL which allows double quotes for strings, so I never knew it was not part of the official SQL

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
$builder->select([
   'customer.id as id',
   'customer.number as number',
   'CONCAT(CONCAT(customer.firstname, \' \'), customer.lastname) as name'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

solution I use in Doctrine 2.4+:

```
$concat = new Query\Expr\Func('CONCAT', $name[$k]);
$concat .= ' as ' . $k;
$concat = str_replace(',', ',\' \',', $concat);
$this->query->addSelect($concat);
```

so $name[$k] is an array of fields, as many as you wish.  I then add some spacing between the fields with the str_replace. $k is the name of the concat field, so the result of $concat is

```
"CONCAT(p.email,' ', h.phoneNumber,' ', p.officialName) as details"
```

Hope this helps someone.  On MySQL database PDO Platform.

Craig