# Why always this error occured when I create table in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE zgd_users_table (
user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
user_mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100),
nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Default Name",
level TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(user_id);
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

Comment: Where is final `)`? `PRIMARY KEY(user_id));`

Comment: You are missing the final closing paren:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bfd4.

Comment: Always? Well... Because you always write invalid SQL I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close your command with `)`! Change your query to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE zgd_users_table (
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    user_mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Default Name',
    level TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
    locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    comment VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);
```

Additional comment about the `"` on `DEFAULT`:

> Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes generally aren't used in SQL, but that can vary from database to database.
>   **Source (see comments too):** https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992331/3840840

Comment: According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) both types of quotes are allowed. The error is the missing `)` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing bracket at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `)` closing bracket. Working query is:

```
CREATE TABLE zgd_users_table (
user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
user_mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100),
nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Default Name",
level TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query you miss ) in query:

```
CREATE TABLE zgd_users_table (
user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
user_mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100),
nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Default Name",
level TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax error 
you missing the closing bracket at end 
do it

```
 CREATE TABLE zgd_users_table (
     user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 user_mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100),
nickname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Default Name",
level TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
 locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
 create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```