# How do I limit a query string in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to construct a simple SELECT query and am not sure of the correct syntax using single and double quotes

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analysed WHERE team = ".'$team');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Comment: For string limitation in the query itself always use a single quote. To limit the query string in PHP use a double quote. Example: `"some string that uses an 'inner string' "`

Comment: try this
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analysed WHERE team = ' ".$team." ' ");

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are for literal strings, and in the code above will produce the string `$team` (*literally*) - but you also need those single quotes in your query if `$team` is a string due to MySQL syntax:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analysed WHERE team = '".$team. "'");
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analysed WHERE team = '{$team}'");
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM analysed WHERE team = '$team'");
```

All of the above should work.

Double quotes (or 'magic' quotes) allow variables to be used as part of the string.

Comment: Excellent - thanks so much!

Comment: Actually just checked further all the above seem to return a result that a record exists even if it does not.  It works ok with LIKE but not = do you have any idea why? thanks again

Comment: `mysql_query` returns true if the query was sucessful - nothing to do with if there was actually a record. To check if there is a record you would have to use some other method - but it's technically a different question altogether and out of scope for this post. FYI, you should be using `mysqli_query` as `mysql_query` is depreciated and isn't secure.