# SQL Job error with OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, jobs, openquery

I am trying to run a SQL job with this TSQL script, and the following error is raised. The code runs well in a query window!

What is the problem with this code in the sql job?

```
SELECT *    
FROM OPENQUERY("192.168.1.1",'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC spNewTest @Param1 = ''Test1''')
```

**Error Message**: 
Executed as user: DOMAIN\USER. Incorrect syntax near '192.168.1.1'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Generally, when you have a problem with a job, copy paste the SQL command into a new query window and try it there. This way the noise of it being a "job" will no longer mask the actual TSQL error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('192.168.1.1','SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC spNewTest @Param1 = ''Test1''')
```

instead of this

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("192.168.1.1",'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC spNewTest @Param1 = ''Test1''')
```

EDIT: The difference between simple comma and double comma is that the second one isn't use it in SQL Server, this post from Vineet in 2010 can support the answer

[What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Thanks Charlie Fish for the observation

Comment: Would be helpful to explain why that would work. Also why would changing from single quotes to double quotes make a difference. Some more explanation might be helpful.

Comment: I tried to run the job with single quote as you said and the error still remains. This same command in a query with does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the double quotes with squares brackets [192.168.1.1] and the job is running as expected.

Thanks.