# INSERT COMMAND :: ERROR: column "value" does not exist

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert, pg-column-does-not-exist-error

I'm using postgresql and I'm trying to insert data into a table `users`. When I do that using

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name, name, password,email) 
    VALUES ("user2", "first last", "password1", "user2@gmail.com" );
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "user2" does not exist
```

This is how the table looks like:

```
Table "public.users"
  Column   |       Type    |  Modifiers                        
 user_name | character varying(50)  | 
 name      | character varying(50)  | 
 password  | character varying(50)  | 
 email     | character varying(100) | 
 user_id   | integer                | not null default nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id)
```

I was able to insert a row, but it is not working now.

Comment: Character constants need single quotes. See the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1992314/1741542 on single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: The error message is simply cryptic

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Character constants need **single quotes**.

Use: `INSERT INTO users(user_name, name, password,email) VALUES ('user2','first last','password1', 'user2@gmail.com' );`

See the manual: [postgresql.org/docs/current/static/…](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

*Note: After I encountered the same problem and almost missed the answer that exists in this page (at the comments section), thanks to @a-horse-with-no-name - I've posted this answer*

Comment: I encountered many bad error messages, but this one is quite interesting. I'm pretty sure I'll end up here again in a year or two.

Answer (score 1):

You use **double quotes** for **VALUES** instead of **single quotes**. That's why you got the error:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name, name, password,email) 
    VALUES ("user2", "first last", "password1", "user2@gmail.com");
            ↑     ↑  ↑          ↑  ↑         ↑  ↑               ↑
```

So, use **single quotes** for **VALUES** instead as shown below, then you can solve the error:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name, name, password,email) 
    VALUES ('user2', 'first last', 'password1', 'user2@gmail.com');
            ↑     ↑  ↑          ↑  ↑         ↑  ↑               ↑
```