# Stuck! How do I join three SQL tables to answer these two questions? Or do I not need to?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm fairly certain I'll need to join three SQL tables to answer these two questions, but I can't figure it out! Question 1 has me completely stumped, but I think I'm close with question 2. It's important to keep in mind that this database doesn't actually exist, only in theory.

Both Question 1 and 2 use the same tables:

**Classes**
ID
Name

**Students**
ID
Name

**ClassesStudents**
ClassID
StudentID

> **Question 1:** Write a SQL query that will return the name of each class and how many students are taking it.
>
> **Question 2:** Write a SQL query that will return the names of classes that the student named "John" is taking. Assume there is only one student with that name in the database.

My guess on Question 1 (WIP):

```
SELECT ClassesStudents.StudentID, ClassesStudents.ClassID, 
Classes.Name
FROM ClassesStudents, Classes;
```

My guess on Question 2:

```
SELECT Classes.Name
FROM Students
JOIN ClassesStudents ON ClassesStudents.StudentID=Students.ID AND 
Students.Name = "John"
JOIN Classes ON Classes.ID=ClassesStudents.ClassID
```

Can anyone please help me out? I've Googled everything I could think of :/

> [image]

Comment: Question 1 Hint:  `JOIN` ClasssesStudents and Classes, `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Still not following :/

Would you be able to provide the answers so that I may dissect them? That's how I learn best.

Comment: How about you work on a query to give you studentID, classID, className first (without `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`)?  Also put the table structure (the table name and field list) into the posting instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Post your query and I will add `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` if you still need help.

Comment: Okay, I added the table names and field lists, as well as my query to give me studentID, classID, and className. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Good effort.  Note that the tables need to be joined.  After that add the COUNT function and Group By.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, just join all the tables together Classes.ID = ClassesStudents.ClassID, ClassesStudents.StudentsID = Students.ID, then count the Student table and group by classes.name
For Question 2, you can use back the joining from question 1 and put a "WHERE" condition after the joining...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my answer for Q1. Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

```
SELECT  
Classes.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM ClassesStudents 
JOIN Classes
ON ClassesStudents.ClassID = Classes.ID
GROUP BY Classes.Name
```

Assume no two classes have the same name.  Otherwise include the ClassID in the query:

```
SELECT ClassesStudents.ClassID,
Classes.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM ClassesStudents 
JOIN Classes
ON ClassesStudents.ClassID = Classes.ID
GROUP BY ClassesStudents.ClassID, Classes.Name
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it's starting to make sense. Was I close with Q2?

Comment: Q2 should work but I would use single quote instead of double quote `'John'`.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: For Q2 you could put `StudentsName = 'John'` as a condition of `WHERE` clause: `SELECT Classes.Name
FROM Students
JOIN ClassesStudents ON ClassesStudents.StudentID=Students.ID 
JOIN Classes ON Classes.ID=ClassesStudents.ClassID WHERE StudentName = 'John'`

Comment: You could test your query in sqlfiddle.com  Here is the fiddle I created to test the queries http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/277fa5

Comment: [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
Key points are in bold, for Q1 you only need 2 tables. Attached is the relationships graph.[image: Students Classes DB]

**Question 1:**
SELECT Classes.ClassName, **Count**(ClassesStudents.StudentID) AS CountOfStudentID
FROM Classes INNER JOIN ClassesStudents ON Classes.ClassID = ClassesStudents.ClassID
**GROUP BY** Classes.ClassName;

**Question 2:**
SELECT Classes.ClassName
**FROM** Students INNER JOIN (Classes INNER JOIN ClassesStudents ON Classes.ClassID = ClassesStudents.ClassID) ON Students.StudentID = ClassesStudents.StudentID
**WHERE** (((Students.StudentName)="John"));

Comment: Thank you for your help!