# How much does is matter if I use double quote for inserting string in tables of SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddl, dml

**Please, understand my question first.**

So, I have been thinking is there any difference if I use **double quote** (") for string in **SQL coding** and not **single quote** (')?

Watch this video (***from 2:30***) from Khan Academy to better understand my question.
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/sql-basics/pt/creating-a-table-and-inserting-data

***I am not using double quote anywhere else it is just for string and for inserting data into table.***

So, what is the problem with it ?

I expect logical answer from the expert SQL Coder.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would use single quote as it makes your SQL compatible with Sql Server.  Not sure what the ANSI standard is, if it is single quote then hands down that would be my choice.

Comment: The ANSI SQL standards define doubles quotes as database object names delimiters, while single quotes are dedicated to string literals

Comment: A few more details are [with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Comment: The expert SQL coder did not get my point, I already know the difference, but I am just not sure what is the problem of using double quote for inserting data into a table. Why no one gets it ?

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes in Sql Vs Double quotes in sql could have seem like a char vs string in other languages.

But, in sql there is as such no difference between the two. It is the general standard to use single qoutes. There are some cases though we require double-qoutes as well i guess it depends on the requirement also

For instance,
If you use variable to store then in order to differentiate the two you can store in double qoutes and use the other in single qoutes.

Comment: I am not using double quote anywhere else it is just for string and for inserting data into table.

So, any problem with it.

Comment: Theres no problem with that it will work. But, it is just that you should follow general conventional method usage which is single qoutes

Comment: I know that I just want to know what is the problem. I mean what error will occur?