# Create an inbox message type of query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've just started learning SQL, so I apologies if this question is a bit of a dummy question.

I have two tables:

1. `direct_messages`
2. `users`

A `direct_messages` table looks like this:

[image]

`receiverId` and `senderId` are foreign keys to my `users` table.

What I'm trying to achieve is a typical inbox message query. Meaning get one message of each message sent that has the same `receiverId` as the logged in user and also get the latest one.

I've tried to get this working almost the whole day and I've come this "far":

```
SELECT *
FROM "direct_messages" tm
LEFT JOIN "users" tu ON "tm.senderId" = "tu.id"
WHERE "tm.createdAt"
ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But I'm just getting `ERROR: column "tm.senderId" does not exist`.

All the help I can get is super appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
As requested, I added some example data: https://gist.github.com/Martinnord/f07bc62389f2ecd0df8e6716dd797a15

What I want is to get a list of messages that has a particular `receiverId`, but only one from each unique `senderId` and get the latest one. Like a typical message inbox.

Comment: Don't use double quotes around column and table names, preferably use non (not sure if single quotes work)

Comment: Please add an example input data and the expected output for that data.  Do you want to find all of the last messages that were sent by a particular user ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql). There's no need to quote everything, it may be [considered harmful](https://blog.lerner.co.il/quoting-postgresql/).

Comment: @Dvorog I've added some data and hopefully described my question in more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people mentioned in the comments you have a problem with your double quotes and they explained how you should handle that.
I will show you how to solve the sql problem that you are having.
I will create a sample `messages` table.

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
  sender_id BIGINT ,
  reciever_id BIGINT,
  message TEXT,
  sent_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

Now lets fill that table with some data:

```
INSERT INTO messages (sender_id, reciever_id, message, sent_at) VALUES
  (1,3,'User 1 to user 3 1 hour ago', '2017-07-10 15:00:00'),
  (1,3,'User 1 to user 3 last','2017-07-10 16:00:00'),
  (2,3,'User 2 to user 3 2 hours ago','2017-07-10 14:00:00'),
  (2,3,'User 2 to user 3 last','2017-07-10 16:00:00');
```

Now, lets say that we want to find all of the last mesasges (by sender_id) that were sent to the user with `id` 3.

So based on the input data, the result should return 2 messages:

1. From user 1 to user 3 with value "User 1 to user 3 last"
2. From user 2 to user 3 with value "User 2 to user 3 last"

That can be achieved with the following query:

```
WITH sender_last_message_time AS (
SELECT sender_id, MAX(sent_at) sent_at FROM messages
WHERE reciever_id = 3
GROUP BY sender_id )
SELECT * FROM messages m
JOIN sender_last_message_time r ON m.sender_id = r.sender_id AND r.sent_at = m.sent_at;
```

Explanation:

I create the `sender_last_message_time` [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html) that holds the last message time (sent by sender_id) for each sender. Once I have sender_id and the time of the last message for that sender_id, I just join the data with the `messages` table in order to fetch the messages.

Comment: Hey! I tried your solution and I fist wonder what `WITH sender_last_message_time` this means. And I'm also getting `ERROR: column "senderid" does not exists` . I am using PSequel to write to try this query btw.

Comment: Have you created the `messages` tables that I created above? I added a small explanation on what `WITH` does. It basically creates a table with two columns: sender_id and sent_at. The value of sent_at is the time of the last sent message to the reciver by the sender.

Comment: As you can see my `messages` table is different than the one you have, but you should be able to make the query work for the one you use.

Comment: Yes, yours works perfect. But when I try to apply the same logic to my table I just get errors

Comment: In that case, you probably have problems with casing, like the user Schwern explained above. Maybe instead of using `senderId = ...` use `"senderId"=...`

Comment: I thought so too. I tried putting single quotes on the column names, now im facing a problem with, `ERROR: type "max" does not exists`

Comment: Max is not a column, it is a function call and it should not be quoted. If you are still learning about databases, I would consider recreating the database without using quotes unless you *explicitly* need them.

Comment: Would you mind creating a chat and maybe work this out? I would greatly appreciate that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189331/discussion-between-dvorog-and-martin-nordstrom).

Answer (score 1):

[Double quoting everything in Postgresql may be considered harmful](https://blog.lerner.co.il/quoting-postgresql/) because of [how double quotes work](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). They should only be used when there's likely to be confusion with a keyword.

`"tm.senderId"` does not mean `senderId` in the `tm` alias. Because the `.` is quoted it means *exactly* the identifier `tm.senderId`. Postgres is looking for a column `tm.senderId` in the table `direct_messages` and not finding it.

Instead you'd write `"tm"."senderId"` careful to quote the table/alias and column separately.

This leads to the next pitfall, casing. Unless they're quoted, Postgres will lower case columns and table names for you.

```
test=# create table direct_messages ( senderId integer );
CREATE TABLE
test=# \d direct_messages 
           Table "public.direct_messages"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 senderid | integer |           |          |
```

(*Note even the table description `"public.direct_messages"` is misleading.*)

And it will do the same to unquoted tables and columns in queries.

```
test=# select * from direct_messages tm where tm.sEnDerID is not null;
 senderid 
----------
(0 rows)
```

But if you quote them, it will look for an exact match.

```
test=# select * from direct_messages tm where tm."sEnDerID" is not null;
ERROR:  column tm.sEnDerID does not exist
LINE 1: select * from direct_messages tm where tm."sEnDerID" is not ...

test=# select * from direct_messages tm where tm."senderId" is not null;
ERROR:  column tm.senderId does not exist
LINE 1: select * from direct_messages tm where tm."senderId" is not ...
                                               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "tm.senderid".

test=# select * from direct_messages tm where tm."senderid" is not null;
 senderid 
----------
(0 rows)
```

There's no ambiguous column names in your query, so remove the double quotes.

```
SELECT *
FROM direct_messages tm
LEFT JOIN users tu ON tm.senderId = tu.id
WHERE tm.createdAt
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

(Side note: it's confusing to mix camelCase `createdAt` and snake_case `created_at`. Pick one style for the project and stick with it.)