# unrecognized problem in java using oracle

Tags: java, oracle11g

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                user=tf1.getText();
                pass=new String(tf2.getPassword());
                try {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","jashan","noor1032"); 
                    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from jashan.student where 'name1'=? and 'password'=?");
                        stmt.setString(1, user);
                        stmt.setString(2, pass);
                    ResultSet Rs=stmt.executeQuery();
                    if(Rs.next())
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "success!!");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect username/password","warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        }
                   }    
                    catch(Exception f)
                        {
                            System.out.println(f);
                        }
            }
```

actually, i want that the code matches the username and password, but it is not doing so...whenever i execute, it shows invalid password/username....i don't know why....i have a table in oracle 11g which has columns student_id, name1,gender,address, email_id, phone_number,and password in the same order as defined. can anyone tell me what is the problem??

[image: Picture of my table]

Comment: I'm not sure you need to put the column names in your prepared statement in single quotes.

Comment: See: [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1992314/5221149)

Comment: *"whenever i execute, it shows invalid password/username"* That's because you enter the wrong name/password. Enter `name1` for name and `password` for password, and you'll get "success!!". That is of course not what you intended, but it *is* what you wrote the code to do, by comparing `user` to **text literal** `'name1'` and comparing `pass` to text literal `'password'`.

Comment: @Andreas i am entering the right username and password, but still it shows the same error

Comment: Debug your Query in an SQL Tool. E.g. PL/SQL-Developer. Then copy it into the java source.

Answer (score 1):

You have given single qoute around your column name that is causing the issue. Remove that and it should work

Change `'name1'` to `name1` and `'password'` to `password` in your query

Comment: first i tried without single quotes only, it didn't work....i tried it again and it is still not working

Comment: the error is 'name1 is invalid identifier' but the name of the column is name1 only

Answer (score 1):

You have managed to create a table with lowercase column names. As you have experienced, it causes trouble as Oracle converts all names (for tables, columns etc.) to upper-case by default.

You have two options:

1. Drop the table and recreate it with uppercase names.
2. Use *double* quotes around the columns names to prevent Oracle from converting them to uppercase:

```sql
select * from jashan.student where "name1"=? and "password"=?
```

Or when you put it in Java:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from jashan.student where \"name1\"=? and \"password\"=?");
```

In any case, *single* quotes around column names is incorrect.

Comment: actually this solution looks fine, but adding double quotes around the name1 and password fields, it creates a problem in query, because double quotes are used to define strings in java.....when i put double quotes, both the fields technically come out of the query.

Comment: thank you very much, i renamed all the attributes into uppercase and it worked

Comment: Yes, in Java code you need to esacpe the double quotes. See my update.

Comment: can you also tell me how to retrieve all the values from the oracle database and display it in jtable....I did it in MySQL and it worked and now i applied the same code fro oracle but it didn't....to see my code please refer to my one more question which i asked 4 days ago