# Why does postgreSQL detect this line as a column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I'm doing this (Postgre)SQL excercize for a course i'm following; the objective is fairly simple i suppose:

> Insert data into courses using the data provided. Make sure id is system generated.

for reference, this is the query to create said table

```
%%sql
CREATE TABLE courses (
course_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
course_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
course_author VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
course_status course_status,
course_published_dt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

and this is the query that i'm trying to run

```
%%sql
INSERT INTO courses (course_id, course_name, course_author, course_status, 
course_published_dt)
VALUES 
("Programming using Python", "Bob Dillon", "published", "2020-09-30"),
("Data Engineering using Python", "Bob Dillon", "published", "2020-07-15"),
("Data Engineering using Scala", "Elvis Presley", "draft"),
("Programming using Scala", "Elvis Presley", "published", "2020-05-12"),
("Programming using Java", "Mike Jack", "inactive", "2020-08-10"),
("Web Applications - Python Flas", "Bob Dillon", "inactive", "2020-07-20"),
("Web Applications - Java Spring", "Mike Jack", "draft"),
("Pipeline Orchestration - Python", "Bob Dillon", "draft"),
("Streaming Pipelines - Python", "Bob Dillon", "published", "2020-10-05"),
("Web Applications - Scala Play", "Elvis Presley", "inactive", "2020-09-30"),
("Web Applications - Python Django", "Bob Dillon", "published", "2020-06-23"),
("Server Automation - Ansible", "Uncle Sam", "published", "2020-07-05");
```

when i run it, the message below appears:

> (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "Programming using Python" does not exist
> LINE 3:     ("Programming using Python", "Bob Dillon", "published", ...

i really don't get why it takes the first value of that row as the column name... what am i doing wrong? The very same slides i'm following picture queries done the same way!

Comment: Double quotes are used to indicate column names (identifiers). Use single quotes around character literals: 'this is a value, not a column name'.  "this is a column name".

Comment: See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: Note: Some databases can use double quotes for string/character literals.  You might find some instructional material using double quotes.  But that is not standard behavior.  Use single quotes.  Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=09d696fdbba9d5bfc81e3d939e70f338

Comment: Hi @castoldie, does your create table code work ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Comment: Remember single/double quotes mean very different things in SQL though they are synonymous and interchangeable in Python.

Comment: just remove `course_id` from you `insert` statement:

`INSERT INTO courses (course_name, course_author, course_status, 
course_published_dt) ...`

and use single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: @JonArmstrong thank you sir!! I had no idea that was a thing

Comment: @Vboka yes it does

Comment: @Alexey course_id is required by the excercize and i don´t have to specify it because it's a SERIAL PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Hi @castoldie can you explain to me what kind of type is  course_status  ? I can not create table with your code : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=03bc59952f20d0bb767eaacc1d9f3f64

Comment: sorry @VBoka this cell was not included:
CREATE TYPE course_status AS ENUM ('published', 'draft', 'inactive');