# (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "name" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

I used double quotes on "NAME" to make it case sensitive but it still doesn't work. I get an error saying that the column "name" doesn't exist.

(i use jupyter notebook and sql magic commands)

```
ppg = [[],[]]
for x in overall_ppg_leaders:
    reg_ppg = %sql SELECT * FROM "rg_player_stats" WHERE "NAME" = :x;
    po_ppg = %sql SELECT * FROM "po_player_stats" WHERE "NAME" = :x;
    ppg[0].append(reg_ppg)
    ppg[1].append(po_ppg)
print(ppg)
```

I get error:

```
* postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:***@localhost/NBA_2021-22
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM rg_player_stats WHERE NAME = 'Kevin Durant';
                                            ^

[SQL: SELECT * FROM rg_player_stats WHERE NAME = %(x)s;]
[parameters: {'x': 'Kevin Durant'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
 * postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:***@localhost/NBA_2021-22
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM po_player_stats WHERE NAME = 'Kevin Durant';
                                            ^

[SQL: SELECT * FROM po_player_stats WHERE NAME = %(x)s;]
[parameters: {'x': 'Kevin Durant'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
 * postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:***@localhost/NBA_2021-22
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM rg_player_stats WHERE NAME = 'Donovan Mitchell...
                                            ^
```

[image: The sql table]

I also noticed that column name with double quotes works when I use cell magic `%%sql` but gives me an error when I use the single line magic `%sql`

This code works fine
[image]

This code gives me an error
[image]

Comment: Well... is there such a column on the table at all?

Comment: @AKX yes there is, i edited the question you can see the screenshot of the table

Comment: Don't wrap it in double quotes. Double quotes generally aren't used in SQL, but that can vary from database to database. Stick to using single quotes. Reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: @IvanSidaruk. Wrong answer. See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) where it explains double quotes are used to case preserve identifiers, among other things.

Comment: 1) Try `...WHERE quote_ident("NAME")`. For more information see [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). 2) Alternate  `...WHERE '"NAME"'`. As in Python `'` or `"` can be used for string quoting.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i tried ```quote_ident()``` it still gives me the same error.
and when i use ```'"NAME"'``` i get empty results.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I solved this issue by using ```"\"NAME\""```
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ```'"NAME"'``` didn't give me an error but it gave me empty results. I don't understand why it didn't work

Comment: I should have tested first, I was wrong on quote_ident() being useful in this case. Did '"NAME"' not work? As it should have done the same thing as "\"NAME\"" with the ' escaping the ". When I do `"\"NAME\"" it turns into '"NAME"'.

Comment: Hmm, must be in how `sql` magic does it's parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using single line magic command `%sql`,
use `"\"NAME\""` instead of "NAME" so that it is case sensitive.

```
ppg = [[],[]]
for x in overall_ppg_leaders:
    reg_ppg = %sql SELECT "\"PPG\"" FROM "rg_player_stats" WHERE "\"NAME\"" = :x;
    po_ppg = %sql SELECT "\"PPG\"" FROM "po_player_stats" WHERE "\"NAME\"" = :x;
    ppg[0].append(reg_ppg)
    ppg[1].append(po_ppg)
print(ppg)
```

This code WORKS