# MySQL unable to use WHERE and JOIN together

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables consisting of Table 1 Person: age_id(PK) and treatment, Table 2 genders: age_id(FK) and age

```
SELECT COUNT(genders.gender_id) AS count, genders.gender
FROM genders JOIN Person on genders.gender_id = Person.gender 
WHERE Person.treatment = “Yes”
GROUP BY genders.gender;
```

I am trying to display the number of people according to gender that has received treatment using JOIN and WHERE but am faced with this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTMQ9.png). The Treatment column consists of rows with either "Yes" or "No" but somehow the WHERE condition is not detecting it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql

Comment: i tried changing to single quotes and faced the same issue

Comment: Looks like you might be copying and pasting from a document that converts quotes into curly quotes.  Try typing the quote directly into your query not copying and pasting.

Comment: These quotes are not even ascii double quotes. They are Left Double Quotation Mark(U+201C). Use regular ascii single quotes for string literals.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that transferring my code from google docs to MySQL would cause the quotes to convert, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(genders.gender_id) AS count, genders.gender
FROM genders JOIN Person on genders.gender_id = Person.gender 
WHERE Person.treatment = 'Yes'
GROUP BY genders.gender;
```

Use single quote instead of double quotes

Single quotes are for Strings Literals (date literals are also strings);
Double quotes are for Database Identifiers;