# Suspend table constraints during SSIS import

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm trying to seed a blank database from the production db via the Import/Export wizard. How do I convince SQL Server to ignore Foreign Key violations?

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737115/turn-off-constraints-temporarily

and you can use DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINT to check that all is well before you turn them back on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to "check constraints" on the OleDbDestination Component. unmark it and it will ignore the foreign keys.

I honestly don't like that option much, so I suggest these two other ways:

1) Always copy the tables on the "inverse" order of the key. For example, if you have a key from A to B, copy table B first and then table A

2) use a Exec SQL Task to disable the foreign keys with the `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT` (example [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/10/01/60719.aspx)) before copy and another to enable after copy