# Insert records from one table to another without violating any constraint in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

There are 2 databases `DB_Main` and `DB_Backup` in SQL Server 2008.

I want to copy the data of `Table1` from `DB_Backup` into `Table1` of `DB_Main`.

The structure of all the tables in both the database is same. Both the tables in both the database have foreign key, primary key constraint.

When I try to copy data of `Table1` from `DB_Backup` into `Table1` of `DB_Main` with this query:

```
Insert into [DB_Main].[Table1] 
    Select * 
    from [DB_Backup].[Table1];
```

I get this foreign key error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Table1_Table3".  The conflict occurred in database "DB_Main",
>   table "Table3", column 'RequestID'.

Please let me know any simple way to copy all the records of `Table1` from `DB_Backup` into `Table1` of `DB_Main`, without violating any constraint?

Please reply

Comment: Please tag the database type (SQL Server?) This error means that you also need to load data into `Table3`. There is a piece of data in a column in `Table1` that needs to first exist in `Table3`. Take a look at the foreign key and work out what column needs the data.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thank You for the reply. `Table3` already have data in it. Its just due to some reason `Table1` all the data got deleted from DB_Main database so I am insert the backup data from DB_Backup database. Please let me know what shall I change in my query ?

Comment: Did you check the constraint? Did you do any reading on foreign key constraints? I suggest you don't undertake a data patching exercise without knowing about foreign key constraints. Anyway I can't tell you what to change as you have not posted the constraint definition. We need to know what column in `Table1` the constraint is attached to.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I request you to please review the error again in my posted question. I had mentioned the column name `RequestID` this column is Foreign Key in `Table1` and Primary Key of `Table3`. Please note that I am new in Database. Please let me know what other info you need related to the error, I will let you know about it. Please reply

Comment: What this means is that for example you are trying to insert a record into `Table1` which has `RequestID` = 75. The foreign key constraint means that there _must_ be a record with `RequestID` = 75 in `Table3`.... and there currently isn't. So this means you also need to load data into `Table3`. Does that make sense?

Comment: In `Table3' I have record with `RequestID=75` (primaryKey) , but `Table1` is empty , in which RequestID is foreign Key.

Comment: 75 was an example. I'm just guessing. You are inserting data into `Table1`. FInd all the keys with `Select DISTINCT RequestID from [DB_Backup].[Table1]`. Now find the ones that are missing from the foreign table with this: `Select DISTINCT RequestID from [DB_Main].[Table3] WHERE Request_ID NOT IN (Select DISTINCT RequestID from [DB_Backup].[Table1])`. Do you get any? These are the ones that need to first be inserted into `Table3`

Comment: ok got it. Thank you so much Mr. Nick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87853/discussion-between-user3196511-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that for example you are trying to insert a record into `Table1` which has for example `RequestID = 75`. The foreign key constraint means that there must be a record with `RequestID = 75` in `Table3`.... and there currently isn't.

So this means you also need to load data into `Table3`

To find the records actually causing the issue run

```
Select DISTINCT RequestID from [DB_Backup].[Table1]
```

Some of these request ID's need a 'parent' record in `Table3`

To find the specific ones run

```
Select RequestID from [DB_Main].[Table3] 
WHERE Request_ID NOT IN (
    Select DISTINCT RequestID from [DB_Backup].[Table1]
    )
```

You need to insert these into `Table3`:

```
insert into Table3(Request_ID, OtherColumn)

Select RequestID, OtherColumn from [DB_Backup].[Table3] 
WHERE Request_ID NOT IN (
    Select DISTINCT RequestID from [DB_Main].[Table3]
    )
```

Then you can load your other records.

Answer (score -2):

Drop or Disable constraint FK_Table1_Table3 before inserting and enable after it.

To Disable:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_Table3
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737115/turn-off-constraints-temporarily-ms-sql)

to Enable

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_Table3
```

Comment: and violate database integrity?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please let me know how to do that ?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yep. This way is use to load big amount of data in short time. Of course you should check itegrity by your own before load of solve consistency problems after it.

Comment: @ViktorBardakov: Thank you for the reply. I just want to confirm that doing this will not harm any data or Table structure in Database ?? as **DB_Main** is the Live database I am using for my application. Please reply

Comment: Yes it will harm data. You have a foreign key issue and you don't fix that by turning off the foreign key. Its like if you see a burglar you just turn off the burglar alarm. You fix it by fixing the data.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thank you for the reply. Noted.