# SQL Server: How to insert a row when there is a foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, foreign-keys, constraints

I want to insert without deleting a foreign key constraint. I have 2 tables, table1 and table2. When I try to insert into table1, I get something along the following error:

> The insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint "fk_dbo.table1.dbo.table2id"'

This error occurs even after I use `ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL`

So basically I want to insert values into some foreign key columns without deleting the foreign key constraints. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The way to do it is to insert a corresponding value into the parent table first, then insert into the child table - that satisfies the constraint and retains the referential integrity of your database.

Comment: @Turophile
the thing is im using ssis and i have lots of tables with correct data in them.  I know the data is correct.  I want to insert these keys in an order that is convenient to me. (It is going to be a huge task to figure out the perfect order to populate all tables according to key constraints)

Comment: In that case, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737115/turn-off-constraints-temporarily-ms-sql