# check if foreign keys are enabled on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to see on a specific table if the foreign keys are enabled. So to check which of the below options is enabled on a table in a ms-sql server?

It's enabled / disabled like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26552264/3883682):

```
-- Disable the constraints on a table called tableName:
ALTER TABLE tableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

-- Re-enable the constraints on a table called tableName:
ALTER TABLE tableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
---------------------------------------------------------

-- Disable constraints for all tables:
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'

-- Re-enable constraints for all tables:
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all'
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: huh, I thought I described my question pretty well. The code is an example to set the constraint checks, bud I want to see on an table which of those options is set. So for an table if the foreign keys are enabled or not?